# Исключение при Ctrl+C

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Вот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void pause()
{
 cout << "Press ENTER key to continue or CTRL+C for exit ..." << endl;
 cin.get();
 cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail(), EOF);//flush input buffer
}

int main()
{
 while(true)
 {
 cout << "Exception in this cout on second while" << endl;
 pause();
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Суть функции `pause()` просто, задержать выполнение программы до ввода клавиши <kbd>Enter</kbd>, либо завершить программу нажатием клавиши <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>(стандартное сочетание закрытия программы из консоли). Вроде по коду всё ок, нажимаю <kbd>Enter</kbd> оно делает прокрутку по циклу, ровно освобождает буфер и т. д., но как только нажимаю <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> оно не завершает, код доходит до функции `cout` (в цикле `while`) и мне Visual Studio выкидывает исключение:

> First-chance exception at 0x768f6d67 in Lab2.exe: 0x40010005: Control-C.

и отладчик висит на Kernel32.dll. Почему такая ошибка вылазит? Пробывал убирать и переписывать по разному строки:

```
cin.get();
cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail(), EOF);
```

всё равно та же история, не понимаю я эти Std. При нажатии <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> затем <kbd>Enter</kbd> программа вообще входит в бесконечный цикл без остановки на `cin.get()`.

Может кто-то поможет разобраться почему такие чудеса возникают, просто интересно стало разобрать природу такой реакции консоли и `iostream` на <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> и <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

Ах и еще, среда Visual Studio 2010

Comment: В `cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail(), EOF);` писать `EOF` избыточно. Можно этот аргумент опустить. Под линуксом работает идеально. Ctrl+Z отправляет процесс спать, Ctrl+C рубит его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё выглядит так, как будто отладчик Visual Studio сам перехватывает Ctrl+C и прерывает выполнение. Там у него в настройках где-то есть галочка, которая выключает перехват Ctrl+C отладчиком.

Comment: Хм действительно, компильнул without debugger проблема с CTRL+C испарилась спасибо, тут явно дело в отладчике, но всё же осталось не понятно почему CTRL+Z вгоняет код в бесконечный цикл

Comment: CTRL+Z. Команда откат или отмена последнего действия.
У вас цикл вечный, который ограничивается только cin, который отменяется.